# yarn uninitialized constant Socket::SOL_TCP

Tags: ruby, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to use yarn here and got into a problem that might be related to ruby.
On executing any `yarn` command, I get the error `.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/yarn-0.1.1/lib/yarn/server.rb:14:in <class:Server>': uninitialized constant Socket::SOL_TCP (NameError)`

Error Stack:

`` $ yarn 
.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/yarn-0.1.1/lib/yarn/server.rb:14:in <class:Server>': uninitialized constant Socket::SOL_TCP (NameError)
Did you mean?  Socket::SO_TYPE
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/yarn-0.1.1/lib/yarn/server.rb:6:in <module:Yarn>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/yarn-0.1.1/lib/yarn/server.rb:4:in <top (required)>'
    from .../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
    from .../.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/yarn-0.1.1/bin/yarn:26:in <top (required)>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/yarn:23:in load'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/yarn:23:in <main>'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in eval'
    from .../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>' ``

Any ideas on the cause of this?

Answer (score 22):

You may have the [yarn gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/yarn) installed (a web-server) and its associated executable at the same time that you are running the `yarn` command for [the package manager](https://yarnpkg.com). If so, and you intend to use the package manager, then simply `gem uninstall yarn` and `y` to remove the executable when prompted. All that you should need to run the package manager is to `brew install yarn`.

Comment: For Windows, use [chocolatey install yarn](https://chocolatey.org/packages/yarn).

Answer (score 5):

You should delete yarn gem:

```
gem uninstall yarn
```

and install yarn again:

```
yarn
```

> yarn install v1.9.2. 
>   success Already up-to-date.
>   ✨  Done in 0.77s.

And after that, last step

```
yarn build
```

> - 248 hidden modules ✨  Done in 4.95s.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error in ruby-2.2.4. I was able to overcome the problem by updating ruby to the latest version.

It looks like the Socket Server is crashing, so older ruby version may have an updated socket class?